# Why would object.pk be None in get_success_url in CreateView?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a `CreateView` to which after creation I'd like the user to be directed to the `DetailView` for that newly created instance.

```py
class ModelCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Model
    template_name = 'models/model-create-template.html'
```

In my `get_success_url` method, I use `self.object.pk`, but it is `None`.

```py
    def get_success_url(self):
        return f'/model/{self.object.pk}'
```

---

```py
class ModelCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Model
    template_name = 'models/model-create-template.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return f'/model/{self.object.pk}'
```

Model for reproduction:

```py
class Model(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

Using this model with the code above will reproduce that `self.object.pk` or `self.object.id` is `None` within `get_success_url`.

I can see that I reach a successful `save()` since my `post_save` signals are firing, and `form_valid()` is called as well, since I update the user in this method.

When I look in my debugger at `self.object`, all of the other fields are populated, by `id` and `pk` are both `None`. Looking at the instance in admin, I can confirm these are actually being set correctly, but for some reason at the time of calling `get_success_url` I don't have access to this data.

Is the instance in `self.object` actually the created instance, or is it just representing the fields submitted by the `CreateView` form? If its the former, how could I access the instance in `get_success_url`?

Comment: Please see how to write a [mre], your given code is not enough to reproduce the problem you face... Oh and you imply that you override `form_valid`, are you then calling super?...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat it very much is, though. Its a standard `CreateView` with any model, and overriding `get_success_url` which is a method on `CreateView`. There's really nothing else to it beyond my `form_valid` override which isn't necessary context.

Comment: `form_valid` _is_ necessary context! It is what actually sets `self.object` in the view... I would recommend reading that page though, you seem to just post a question and assume your example is reproducible...

Comment: Using only the code in my post (and I had to create a model with no extra fields, I'll be sure to include that as well) I reproduced the issue, making it by definition a viable reproduction. I added my `form_valid` there as well, although issue also occurs without this on a fresh view.